# what is the waxy white residue in my house pipes

Tags: water

I have had white residue in my dishwasher and did some research and found what I thought to be the answer which was not cleaning my dishes well enough so food residue was building up.

However now my shower was leaking so I took the valve out to replace and found the same reside all over the the valve(see below).

[image]

What could it be?  Just as importantly, what should I do to fix this?

I live in an area with hard water and have a water softener.  I'm not on a septic system either. (I'm on city water).

Comment: could be valve lubricant

Comment: @jsotola.  I guess it COULD be, but I bought a brand new valve which has none of this stuff on it and it's the same gunk that i found in my dishwasher ( or at least looks just like it).

Comment: Is it actually *waxy*? It might just be damp deposits of lime (calcium carbonate) from the hard water.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik.  Hm good question, it's smears like chapstick a bit?  Oily could describe it.  I can let it dry out and see though for sure.

Comment: looks like mineral build up to me.

Comment: Drop some in a puddle of vinegar and see if it fizzes. Or just dissolves - I forget if vinegar is strong enough acid to make lime fizz, or if you need **HCl** for that. Lime is not baking soda, though both are alkaline.

Comment: How old is your home new fixtures are lubricated. Mineral deposits are almost always hard not large and lumpy, do you have a pressure regulator on the water supply?